# Does Magento expect server timezone to match default store timezone?

Tags: magento, datetime

Take a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Date::gmtTimestamp()` :

```
/**
 * Forms GMT timestamp
 *
 * @param  int|string $input date in current timezone
 * @return int
 */
public function gmtTimestamp($input = null)
{
    if (is_null($input)) {
        return gmdate('U');
    } else if (is_numeric($input)) {
        $result = $input;
    } else {
        $result = strtotime($input);
    }

    if ($result === false) {
        // strtotime() unable to parse string (it's not a date or has incorrect format)
        return false;
    }

    $date      = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($result);
    $timestamp = $date->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP) - $date->get(Zend_Date::TIMEZONE_SECS);

    unset($date);
    return $timestamp;

}
```

Assume that `$input` is `"Today"`.
Assume that server timezone is `UTC`.

`$date->get(Zend_Date::TIMEZONE_SECS)` corresponds to difference in seconds between the store timezone and UTC. If Magento default store (I'm testing from Admin) timezone iz `Pacific/Auckland` `(GMT+12)`, the value will be `43200` .

Now, given that Magento is subtracting that difference from the timestamp obtained through `strtotime`, it is obviously expecting that the obtained timestamp matches the store timezone. However, it is not, and by subtracting the NZ time difference from GMT time, the result will be `GMT-12`, instead of `GMT+00`

This behaviour in particular affects applying catalog rules. If you take a look at `catalogrule_product_price`, you will see that rule entries are created for current day, previous day and next day. However, due to the `GMT-12` bug described above, in some occassions, the entries will be made for current day, yesterday, and day before yesterday.

This creates problems on frontend in the following way: In `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::processFrontFinalPrice()` , `$date` value will match NZ timestamp. , which is GMT+12, or in some cases, one day in future from the position of a UTC observer. Since entries in `catalogrule_product_price` will not contain the entry for the next day, this will ultimately result in failure to obtain the catalog rule.

You can trigger execution of this code by applying a catalog rule in admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After significant testing, in short, yes, your base store time zone should match your server time zone.